# Meteor CSS thumbnails

Tags: css, meteor

Have an app with Bootstrap styles. Wanted to create a table with a small picture in it. Therefore I have created a new css file and put in the following:

```
img.small-img {
    width: 20;
    height: 20;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Then in meteor I'm using:

```
<img src="{{url}}" class="small-img" />
```

But it is not working. I checked and the CSS file is certainly compiled in tte Meteor app.

Answer (score 2):

[Units must be specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units) for any non-zero lengths in CSS.

```
img.small-img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```